# Having Trouble Sorting Data by Groups in C

Tags: c

Here is some code I have, it should sort from J,S, then M, but my code only prints the last value. I also need to clean it but I can do that. I just need help sorting it by the groups so that it prints out correctly.
Whenever I try to print it, it just prints 7007 2890.58 J for all the positions.

```
void sortData(int* id, double* amt, char* desig, int Size)
{
    if(Size<=13)
    {
        int i;
        int j;
        double tempAmt;
        int tempId;
    char tempDesig;
    int check=-1;
    for(i=0;i<2;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<Size;j++)
        {
            if(i==0)
            {
                if(*(desig+j)=='J')
                {
                    tempDesig= *(desig+j);
                    tempId= *(id+j);
                    tempAmt= *(amt+j);
                    check++;
                }
            }
            if(i==1)
            { 
                if(*(desig+j)=='S')
                {
                    tempDesig= *(desig+j);
                    tempId= *(id+j);
                    tempAmt= *(amt+j);
                    check++;
                }
            }
            *(desig+j)= *(desig+check);
            *(desig+check)= tempDesig;
            *(amt+j) = *(amt+check);
            *(amt+check)= tempAmt;
            *(id+j)= *(id+check);
            *(id+check)=tempId;
        }
    }
}
else{
    printf("Number of records cant be more than 13\n");
}
}
```

These are the starting values

```
ACCOUNTS         AMOUNTS         DESIGNATION
  1001             1591.63              M
  1011             1503.54              S
  2002             2000.43              M
  3332             2567.99              J
  2112             3112.67              M
  4334             5111.34              S
  6134             7172.23              P
  9009             4999.00              P
  3003             4000.00              S
  4004             5000.00              S
  5005             3000.00              J
  6116             4599.91              S
  7007             2890.58              J
```

This is what it should look like

```
ACCOUNTS         AMOUNTS         DESIGNATION
  7007            2890.58              J
  5005            3000.00              J
  3003            4000.00              S
  4004            5000.00              S
  6116            4599.91              S
  2002            2000.43              M
  1001            1591.63              M
  2112            3112.67              M
```

void sort_data(int *,double *,char *, int): 
int * - Integer pointer holding all the valid account IDs
double * - Double pointer holding all the corresponding valid amounts
char * - Character pointer holding all the corresponding valid designations
int – count of the number of valid records (remember this cannot be 13 anymore)

Now, you need to group them based on the designations, the first group must have the Juniors (J) and then the second group must have the Seniors (S) and the last group must be the Masters(M). Remember you are not sorting anything in ascending or descending order, you are group sorting them. When you swap the positions of designations while grouping, make sure the account IDs and the amounts match too after the grouping.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a [debugger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debugger) to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: Can a solution use structures?

Comment: no we have not learned about structures yet. No array notation all pointer notation

Comment: Your sort is going to go 1 past the end of the array.  The compare needs to stop 1 before size.  Your swap position seems to be off by one as well and will do random, but without debugging, I cannot say for sure.

Comment: What I think is needed is some logic that only swaps if you actually found a 'J' or 'S'. And then you need a case to group 'M', too.

Comment: Gee, I forgot to sort by Newest again...